# sql error - unique constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, primary-key, plsqldeveloper

I have one data migration script like this.

Data_migration.sql

It's contents are

---

```
insert into table1 select * from old_schema.table1;
commit;
insert into table2 select * from old_schema.table2;
commit;
```

---

And `table1` has the `pk_productname` constraint when I execute the script

```
SQL> @ "data_migration.sql"
```

I will get an unique constraint(`pk_productname`) violation. But when I execute the individual sql statements I won't get any error. Any reason behind this. And how to resolve this.

Comment: is the same constraint on old_schema.table1?

Comment: how does the constraint exactly look like and does the table have any triggers?

Comment: @Phil - it's only eight eligible questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The failure of the unique constraint means you are attempting to insert one of more records whose primary key columns collide.

If it happens when you run a script but not when you run the individual statements then *there must be a bug in your script*.  Without seeing the script it is impossible for us to be sure what that bug is, but the most likely thing is you are somehow running the same statement twice.

Another possible cause is that the constraint is deferred.  This means it is not enforced until the end of the transaction.  So the INSERT statement would appear to succeed if you run it without issuing the subsequent COMMIT.

It is common to run data migration without enabled constraints.  Re-enable them afterwards using an EXCEPTIONS table.  This makes it easier to investigate problems.  [Find out more](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/general.htm#i1006825).

Comment: I Knew that there is a primary key violations. :D
I am asking why as a individual statement its working, and the same statement in sql file is giving me an error.